# Can I run python in Visual Studio Code without all the overhead?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have both python and Visual Studio Code installed. However, when I run python within it, it adds a lot of overhead to each run, looking for MS specific python libraries and whatnot. Is there a way to run python code without all of the MS overhead?

In effect, can I configure Visual Studio Code to just kick off a console/terminal call to my local python interpreter with the script name and just run like that? I would be fine if `VSC` would just run something like `C:\python\python.exe myscript.py` and show it to me in the terminal window.

Comment: What has suggested you that Visual Studio Code adds overhead to Python? Can you provide additional details on that?

Comment: @E_net4 Have you seen what the execution of the scripts looks like in the terminal window? Thers' a ton of junk in there that calls out to native MS processes when it could just be a simple call like the one in my question.

Comment: FWIW, no, I have not. Would you like to edit your question to include greater details?

Comment: Is [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) perhaps what you are looking for?

Comment: My understanding is that VSC is doing this under the hood when you specify your python interpreter: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments. Maybe you can provide details of what you're referring to? Also, are you using virtual environments? You can select a virtual env as your interpreter and there shouldn't be any look up of python libs if your virtual env contains it. Python by default will look for dependencies in the following order: current dir where the script is being ran from, python path if specified, standard lib location, then externals within your site_packages dir

Comment: You might try the [CodeRunner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension. It seems to run the Python script as you described.

Comment: @PaulD. Please post your comment as the answer and I will send you the bounty. This solution is exactly what I was looking for and very easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension. It runs the Python script as you described.

Answer (score 1):

Instal node.js and nodemon:

```
npm i -g nodemon
```

then run

```
nodemon --exec pythonVersion filename
```

example

```
nodemon --exec python3.7 file.py
```

On every file change, this re-run command.

Good idea is to put this script into .sh file

Comment: I appreciate the creativity but there has to be an easier way to go about it than installing NPM

Comment: I use this method, because I'm js programmer :) fill free to share your idea about better workflow with python and Code.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you do right click -> "Run Python File in Terminal", it should do what you are looking for.